# Практическая транскрипция с украинского на русский

Tags: транскрипция

Добра всем!!! Скажите пожалуйста знатоки филологии и лингвистики, как передаётся в практической транскрипции украинская буква Ее(произносится как русское Э!) -в русский язык, как Э или как Е(орфограически)? Например имя Семен(украинское написание имени) в русском будет записано только однозначно как СЭмЭн или возможно вариант написания как СЕмЕн через два Е, или допустимы оба варианта начертания в русском языке СЭмЭн и СЕмЕн, а произношение гласных Е в первом и втором слогах можно читать как Э. Замечу что именно практическая транскрипция(что передаёт иностранные имена собственные в документах!), а не фонетическая что в квадратных скобках. Также украинское имя Артем(записано по украински и читается по-русски как АртЭм!), в русском написании (практическая транскрипция!) -будет записан как АртЭм или может быть записан в русском и как АртЕм(через Е без точек!)